# Z axis not working as expected, OpenGL Quad

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

The right end blue rectangle should come below the red rectangle's bottom end. Z-axis is not working even after I tried changing all z values. The red and green rectangle is working fine.

Display Function:

```
void display() {

    glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
   
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.6, -0.8);
    glVertex3f(-0.2, 0.9, -0.8);
    glVertex3f(0.8, -0.1, 0.8);
    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.4, 0.8);
    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.8, 0.8);
    glVertex3f(0.3, 0.5, 0.8);
    glVertex3f(-0.7, -0.5, -0.8);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, -0.2, -0.8);
    glColor3f(0,0,1);
    glVertex3f(0.6, 0, -0.8);
    glVertex3f(0.6, -0.3, -0.8);
    glVertex3f(-0.9, -0.3, 0.8);
    glVertex3f(-0.9, 0, 0.8);
    glEnd();
```

main Function:

```
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutCreateWindow("Q1 - Background Color set"); 
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
    gluOrtho2D(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glutDisplayFunc(display); 
    glutMainLoop();
```

[Expected ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXBnM.png)

But I'm getting output like this:
[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri8ju.png)

Comment: You have to enable the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test). - `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`

Comment: You should not use glBegin-glEnd. You really should not.
These functions are deprecated and low-performance

Comment: @DimaRich great for learning though. Imagine if you had to create and upload vertex buffers just for this little test program.